# count-based vs. tumbling window

Tags: stream, window

In Stream Processing, what's the difference between a count-based (aka tuple-based) window and a tumbling window?
From my perspective, they are the same:
The tumbling window sets its new (start,end)-pointers, each time a certain number of elements has arrived (it is a sliding window with size=slide). And this is also what the count-based window does.

can someone explain the difference to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A count window is sized by the number of event that are inside of it. A count window does not have any specific amount of time that it is going to be valid.

A tumbling window has fixed timespan and will create a new windows of data based on the timespan it is configured with. Any events that fall into that timespan will be used in the aggregates functions of the window.

[Using Event Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee842704.aspx)

It takes a little digging to find this link but it paints a very clear picture of the window types with graphical timelines to illustrate how data behaves inside each.

[Windows in StreamInsight: The Basics](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/streaminsight/archive/2010/11/23/windows-part-1-the-basics.aspx)

This page has a solid graphical example of what it means to be a tumbling window.

Comment: again a question: Isn't your definition of "tumbling window" actually a time-based window? So what's the difference between a tumbling and a time-based window?

Comment: A tumbling window is a time-based window. It is hopping window where the hop and the timespan are the same.